# Difference between 1.3.5 identify input purpose and 3.3.2 labels or intruction

Tags: accessibility

I want to know the difference between WACG 2.1 guideline 1.3.5 identify input purpose and 3.3.2 labels or instruction.

I know that identify the input purpose mainly for the input field should have clear and descriptive label and should have descriptive instruction like password should have atlease 6 characters. and also auto-fill functionality implement in all form field. so user can able to interact with the form field, input field easily.

wheras labels or instruction is also similar that it should have proper label name and clear instruction visible.

could you please provide some sample website to understand the difference between these 2 guidline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both guideline 1.3.5 "Identify Input Purpose" and 3.3.2 "Labels or Instructions" aim to improve the accessibility of web content for users with disabilities, especially those who use assistive technologies such as screen readers. However, they focus on different aspects of the accessibility of forms.

Guideline 1.3.5 is concerned with ensuring that form controls are programmatically associated with their labels or instructions, which enables assistive technologies to accurately convey the purpose of each control to users. This can include using accessible names, descriptions, or ARIA attributes to identify the input purpose of each form control. It is important to provide clear and descriptive input labels and instructions so that users can easily understand what input is expected of them.

Guideline 3.3.2, on the other hand, focuses on providing labels or instructions that are visible on the page, rather than only programmatically associated with form controls. The purpose of this guideline is to ensure that all users can understand what input is expected of them, regardless of whether they are using an assistive technology or not. This can include providing visible labels for each form control and using clear instructions to explain what information is required.

To better understand the difference between these two guidelines, let's take an example of a login form. For guideline 1.3.5, you would ensure that each input field is associated with a clear and descriptive label, and that any additional instructions are programmatically associated with the input control. For example, the "Username" input field would have a label that reads "Username," and the "Password" input field would have a label that reads "Password," and an additional instruction that reads "Your password must be at least 6 characters long."

For guideline 3.3.2, you would ensure that the labels and instructions are visible on the page and easily understandable. For example, you would use the same labels as above, but you would also ensure that they are clearly visible on the page, and that any additional instructions are provided in a way that is easy to understand. This can include using color contrast, typography, and layout to ensure that the labels and instructions are easy to read and understand.

Here are some sample websites to help you understand the difference between the two guidelines:

- The W3C Web Accessibility Initiative (WAI) provides a list of examples of common accessibility issues, including examples of forms that violate these guidelines: https://www.w3.org/WAI/test-evaluate/preliminary/
- The WebAIM website also provides information and resources on accessible forms: https://webaim.org/techniques/forms/